# Adding Image to excel Export in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2014

I am exporting excel sheets through SSIS export, and creating excel sheet at run time using execute sql task.
Now the client needs a logo(image) to be attached to the excel sheet on top of data part. Do we have any way out to do that.

NB: we cannot use "file system task" to copy a pre-existing excel file as we have to create the task on runtime. cannot copy a excel sheet from any other location.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a script task in ssis and write a VBA code to insert the logo to the cell.

Comment: @aman6496 i provided a c# script task code, you ignored my answer and asked the [same question again!!](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195384/copy-logo-to-excel-ssis-script)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script task to achieve that, you can benefit from the `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` library to achieve that, you can copy the image from a file using the following code:

```
Image ExcelImage = Image.FromFile(strFilePath);
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(ExcelImage ,true);
```

And paste it to excel sheet using the following code:

```
Excel.Worksheet ThisSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ThisWorkBook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range oRange = (Excel.Range)ThisSheet.Cells[10,1];
ThisSheet.Paste(oRange,ExcelImage);
```

**Detailed code provided in the following link:**

- [How to programmatically add a Picture or Icon to an Excel WorkSheet using C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5bb5eb47-ea5e-4d97-a794-6266122552ea/how-to-programmatically-add-a-picture-or-icon-to-an-excel-worksheet-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral)